# yii : CDbCriteria print out wrong result

Tags: php, yii

problem : CDbCriteria print out wrong result.

This is the model search function.

```
public function summary()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = 't.*';

        if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Reviewer')):
            $criteria->addSearchCondition('t.reviewers',Yii::app()->user->id,false, 'AND');
        endif;

        if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Implementer')):
            $criteria->addSearchCondition('t.implementers',Yii::app()->user->id,false, 'OR');
        endif;

        if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Creator')):
            $criteria->compare('t.creator',Yii::app()->user->id, false, 'OR');
        endif;

        $criteria->compare('request_type_id',$this->request_type_id);
        $criteria->compare('request_category_id',$this->request_category_id);
        $criteria->compare('financial_type_id',$this->financial_type_id);
        $criteria->compare('urgency_id',$this->urgency_id);
        $criteria->compare('eta_date',$this->eta_date,true);

        if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Reviewer') || Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Implementer')):
            $criteria->join   = "JOIN profiles p ON (p.user_id = t.creator)";
            if($this->creator):
                $criteria->addSearchCondition('p.firstname',$this->creator, true, 'AND');
            endif;
        endif;

        if(isset($this->status)):
            $criteria->compare('t.status',$this->status);
        endif;



        $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>false,
        ));
        $_SESSION['all'] = $data;


        $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',
                        Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
        $_SESSION['limited'] = $data; 

        return $data;
    }
```

above code was print out the query when I trace with CWebLogRoute but there are no record.

> Querying SQL: SELECT t.* FROM `request` `t` JOIN profiles p ON
>   (p.user_id = t.creator) WHERE t.reviewers LIKE :ycp1 LIMIT 10

When I change those query to following one, it was print out the records.

> SELECT t.*  FROM  `request`  `t`  JOIN profiles p ON ( p.user_id =
>   t.creator )  WHERE t.reviewers LIKE  '%3%' LIMIT 0 , 30

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('t.reviewers',Yii::app()->user->id,false, 'AND');
```

to

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('t.reviewers',Yii::app()->user->id, true, 'AND');
```

Also check format of `reviewers` and how it write down in the records: it's maybe record as ' 3', '3 ', or ' 3 '.

It's have to update records by `update request set reviewers = trim(reviewers)`